# Java Sets to Array

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, set

I'm converting a Java set to an array like: `Integer[] nums= numbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);`

Say I have that line in a method that I call multiple times. Would the nums array be the same every time (stays in the same order), or would it be random in which order it's in?

I'm using this in a Spring Boot project, and SQL doesn't support arrays, so I'm saving them as sets instead; this particular bit is used to determine player order, and the method it's in gets the next player. I'm trying not to get repeating players.

If you have a better way of doing this as well, I'm all ears

Comment: You can use some kind of ordered set like TreeSet (order determined by the values), or LinkedHashSet (order determined based on the insertion order). Then the order will remain the same.  If you use HashSet, the order will be controlled by the hashing of the values (not directly in your control), but probably will remain the same every time.

Comment: [The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) directly answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

`toArray()` is only guaranteed to stick to a particular order if it's a Set with a defined iteration order. In practice, almost any implementation will return a consistent order for a single instance, even if that order is undefined. But if you want to adhere to the spec, it's best to use an ordered set like `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet`. If you don't control creation of the set, you can always copy it to an ordered set to ensure consistent iteration.